# trying to wrap my head around exceptions and when to use them

Tags: c#, exception

I'm not new to coding, I been doing it for a long time, at work I used Java so I just used a try-catch block when the compiler told me to. In c# because exceptions can bubble up the compiler doesnt force you to use it. I know that I should use try-catch blocks when I can recover from an exception, but that honestly doesnt help me much because I dont ever feel the need to use them. With database I just use a using statement and if the code is in a web Api and it fails because it cant connect with the database, it automatically returns a 500 internal server error, so I dont actually need to do anything with it.

I been reading a lot about the subject but can't actually think about when should I use a try-catch block instead of just a using or doing nothin, and I know this is probably holding me back from improving.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not all-encompassing. I'm just going to try to show a few examples.

**Logging**

Using exceptions can be very useful for logging errors. You may even want to re-throw the exception when you are done logging. Knowing what exceptions are being thrown, when they are thrown, how often, etc... can be very useful for debugging or improving your code base.

Example:

```
try
{
  DoThingThatFails();
}
catch (ExpectedException ex)
{
  LogException(ex, DateTime.Now);

  //rethrow the exception
  throw;
}
```

**Building a Library**

This could be an internal or public library. Exceptions are a great way to handle incorrect or unsupported operations. Say you have a class that needs to take a string. It absolutely needs to have a valid, non-null string passed to it. If the user of the Library (could be you or someone else) passes in an invalid value, like `null`, you can throw an exception.

Example:

```
class Example
{
  //name must be a valid, non-empty string
  public Example(string name)
  {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
      throw new InvalidOperationException("The name parameter was null or empty");

    //Initialize your new object
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I adopted try / catch in any non trivial code I write.  If I want to handle a specific exception I add a catch block for that, if I don't I have a standard block I use that will pass up information I would find useful.

In general terms though, there is a ton of info on the subject on the web.  I recommend doing some reading and decide what approach fits you best.

Answer (score 0):

A using block doesn't let you recover from your exception, it just ensures resources are disposed in the event of an uncaught exception. It is critical for you to understand exception handling in your application. You don't need to catch every exception but you should at least catch exceptions at the entry point of your application to prevent crashing.

Lets use an example since that helps me understand concepts best.

Imagine we are creating a WPF application and when a user presses a button a database call would be submitted and some resources would be returned. If your database was offline for whatever reason and you werent calling your database in a try/catch but were calling it in a using block, the application would crash and it would leave a bad impression with your users or not help you with troubleshooting reporting. If we introduce a try/catch around our database call we can more gracefully let the user know of the error and handle our database issues.

```
try 
{
     //Some db access has failed
}
catch(DbOfflineException ex)
{ 
    // Show message box to user 
    // Notify IS DB Team about critical issue
    // Rethrow if our calling method also has a try catch
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // If the exception isn't of type DbOfflineException we
    // would get to this catch block and could handle differently
}
```

You can also chain different exception types if you wanted specific handling for DbOfflineExceptions or Generic Exceptions which is demonstrated above.

Check out this article for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are a way to seperate error handling code from business logic code. Before exception handling you have error handling after each function call in worst case and check if an error occurs over the return value. This makes the code not readable and you can forget to check error codes.

In your case the framework catches all exceptions and returns an internal server error. This is a generic exception handling. It's ok so the service doesn't stop unexcpectedly. But I think you need to know something about the error and save it in a log file or has to inform the user more specific which error occurs. This is when you should use exception handling.